# Синхронизировать ключи строк в android и ios

Tags: java, android, ios, строки, swift

Необходимо создать один файл с ключами (очевидно чтобы удешевить работу переводчиков) У нас два проекта: android и ios. Переводы хранятся в POEditor, но в ходе разработки вполне естественно произошла рассинхронизация. Лазить руками и выискивать нужные значение, исправлять им ключи - совсем не хочется. Большинство переводов взято с макета дизайна, т.е. значения одинаковые,но ключи возможно разные -> задача вполне актуальная.

Я думал написать небольшую программу, который бы скармливал файлы android И ios. Далее по значениям искал ключи. Если значения одинаковые, а ключи нет - выводил бы строку в файл, как строку ключ которой нужно синхронизировать.

Может кто-нибудь знает решение "из коробки"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вот это вам подойдет:

- https://tproger.ru/partnered/lokalise/
- https://habr.com/company/redmadrobot/blog/302682/
- https://events.yandex.ru/lib/talks/8/